# How to hard code struct variables in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have a Julia struct:

```
struct WindChillCalc
    location::Tuple;
    w_underground_url::String;

    WindChillCalc(location, wug) = new(location, w_underground_url);
end
```

How do I hard code w_underground_url to contain "someString" upon the constructor of WindChillCalc being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write for example:

```
struct WindChillCalc{T}
    location::T;
    w_underground_url::String;

    WindChillCalc(location::T) where {T <: NTuple{2, Real}} =
        new{T}(location, "some string");
end
```

and now Julia automatically creates a concrete type for you:

```
julia> WindChillCalc((1, 2.5))
WindChillCalc{Tuple{Int64,Float64}}((1, 2.5), "some string")
```

Note that I have restricted the type of the parameter to be a two element tuple where each element is a `Real`. You could of course use another restriction (or use no restriction).

With this approach your code will be fast as during compile time Julia will know exact types of all fields in your struct.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like below

```
struct testStruct
           x::Real
           y::String    
           testStruct(x,y) = new(x,"printThis")     
       end

test = testStruct(1,"")
test2 = testStruct(2,"")

println(test.y)
println(test2.y)
```

It prints "printThis" for any object.

Comment: Maybe even `testStruct` constructor should not take `y` positional argument as it is not used. The other thing is that `x` now has type `Real` and usually you would want it to be a concrete type for performance reasons (e.g. one could make `testStruct` parametric that inherits the type parameter from the type of `x`).

Comment: Yes.. I agree with you.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński I would be interested to see what the code would look like for a parametric constructor that only took one input argument :)

Comment: I have added an example in the answer.